# the $ in backbone.js View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

What's the difference between jQuery $ and this.$ in Backbone.js View? in a View, I listened to a collection's reset event to empty an element by using below code

```
//code in View
this.$("#the_id").empty();
```

however it did not empty my element, then I changed the code to

```
$("#the_id").empty();
```

this time it works. so, why this.$ does not do the work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `this.$( selector )` in a view is same as calling `$( selector, this )` or `$(this).find( selector )`.

It gives context for the selector I.E. only elements under `this` are searched to match the selector whereas normal jQuery `$(selector)` starts the search from the entire document's root.

Your view should not manipulate elements that it doesn't own, if calling `this.$("#the_id").empty();` doesn't do anything it means that the element wasn't under the view's "area of control" or doesn't exist to begin with.

Comment: I used the same event binding to listen to the collections' add event with the handler this.$('#the_id').append(view.render().el) and it works. but why this.$("#the_id").empty() did not work in the collection's reset event handler?

Comment: @Shuping are you binding the handler's context to the correct `this` object?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your remind, I bond the handler to an incorrect context. your answer resolved my problem!